# Greedy algorithm for fitting subintervals on a wire

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Im currently playing around with some greedy algorithms.

I have this problem description:

```
There is a long electrical wire of length ℓ
centimetres between two poles where birds like to sit. After a long day at work you like to watch 
the birds on the wire from your balcony. 
Some time ago you noticed that they don’t like to sit closer than d centimetres from each other. In 
addition, they cannot sit closer than 6 centimetres to any of the poles, since there are spikes
attached to the pole to keep it clean from faeces that would otherwise damage and weaken it. 
You start wondering how many more birds can possibly sit on the wire

Given numbers ℓ and d, how many additional birds can sit on the wire given the positions of the  
birds already on the wire? For the purposes of this problem we assume that the birds have zero width.

The first line contains three space separated integers: the length of the wire ℓ, distance d and 
number of birds n already sitting on the wire. 
The next n lines contain the positions of the birds in any order. 
All number are integers, 1≤ℓ,d≤1000000000 and 0≤n≤20000. 
(If you have objections to the physical plausibility of fitting that many birds on a line hanging 
between two poles, you may either imagine that the height of the line is 0 cm above ground level, or 
that the birds are ants instead.) 
You can assume that the birds already sitting on the wire are at least 6 cm from the poles and at least d centimetres apart from each other.
```

And I must output a Integer, which is the max amount of additional birds that there is room for on the wire.

**sample input and output**
in         out
22 2 2     3
11
9
and
in         out
47 5 0     8

**attempt**

My initial thought was that do some calculation on how much free space was on the wire. In the case of my first sample input here The array would look something like this:

[image]

(here red squares are places on the wire too close to the poles, and blue ones are already occupied)

Now i would just iterate over this array, and as soon as i hit a "free" item, then place a new bird there, and mark its d-1 neighbors as occupied if they are not already.

I will now go through a hand execution of this idea, where I will iterate with i through the list, and colour the newly occupied places yellow:

[image]
Next we land at i = 15, and hit another empty spot
[image]

This however gives me a different result than my testcases, I must be doing something wrong?
Also I would very much like some comments on the general methodology, is there any way I could be doing this smarter?

I iterate on and next time I hit a empty spot: